# Sharepoint 2013 Search crawling extra data

Tags: search, url, item, crawl, index

The BDC content source I made was crawling "extra"/"garbage"/"unnecessary" data. The external database view only shows 6 items but the search results show 7 items. Crawl log for the content source also shows 7 crawled items. What could be causing this and what can I check to keep this CS from crawling that URL. I also tried recreating the BDC model and content source but still no luck. I know you can remove the URL from being indexed on the next crawl but that option seems to be not working. The URL is still being crawled even if that option from removing it from the next crawl has been selected.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the "right" and "wrong" data? It has to be something in the ECT.

Answer (score 0):

For unnecessary lists and items, there is an option under settings: *List settings -> Advanced settings -> Allow items from this list to appear in search results : NO* .